# Python: Read a list with tree depth level and output a tree like nested list

Tags: python, list, recursion, tree, nested

So here's my problem:

I have successfully parsed a text file with line indention level in to a list like:

```
A = [[1,'a'],[1,'b'],[2,'c'],[2,'d'],[1,'e'],[2,'f']]
```

Each element in list `A` is a list of length 2. Each element corresponds to a line read from the text file. `A[x][0]` is the `indent level` of the line in the text file, `A[x][1]` is the content of the line where `x` is the index of any element in `A`.

For e.g. `A[1] = [1,'b']` where `1` is the indent level and `'b'` is the line text.
`A[2]` and `A[3]` are children of `A[1]` i.e. sub indented lines.

I am trying to get an output list which will be in the following format:

```
B = [['a'],['b',['c','d']],['e',['f']]]
```

This way when I iterate over `B[x][0]` I will get only the first level indented items and be able to recursively go to each element.

The algorithm should be able to handle infinite depth i.e if `A[3]` was followed by element `[3,'z']` it should be a nested list of `A[3]`.

I have explored some other posts that solve a similar problem and use `itertools.groupby` but unfortunately haven't been able to understand them enough to be able to apply it to my problem.

Really appreciate your help folks!

Comment: Why is `'b'` in a sublist, although it's on the same level as `'a'`? Why isn't `'d'` in its own sublist then? Could you clarify the rules?

Comment: -a
-b
--c
--d
-e
--f

So c and d are relevant to b and f is relevant to e.
The root list will only contain elements from level 1 i.e. a, b and e
but since b and e have children, they need to be if b i added as an element of the root list,
the relationship with the children will be lost

Comment: It won't be lost: in `['a', 'b', ['c', 'd'], 'e', ['f']]` each sublist is "relevant" to the previous element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this simple stack-based algorithm:

```
A = [[1,'a'],[1,'b'],[2,'c'],[2,'d'],[1,'e'],[2,'f']]
stack = [ [] ]
for level, item in A:
    while len(stack) > level:
        stack.pop()
    while len(stack) <= level:
        node = (item, [])
        stack[-1].append(node)
        stack.append(node[1])

result = stack[0]
```

This creates a structure like:

```
[('a', []), ('b', [('c', []), ('d', [])]), ('e', [('f', [])])]
```

which, IMO, is more convenient to work with, but it should be no problem to convert it to yours if needed:

```
def convert(lst):
    return [ [x, convert(y)] if y else x for x, y in lst]

result = convert(stack[0])
print result
# ['a', ['b', ['c', 'd']], ['e', ['f']]]
```

Comment: `A = [[1,'a'],[3,'b']]` isn't working properly. Changing line `node = (item, [])` with `node = ((item if len(stack) == level else None), [])` repairs it.

Comment: thanks! this is pretty much what I wanted to go for. How can we get the output without the empty lists?

Answer (score 0):

Recursive solution, method returns formated list for a part of an input list that is for and below given level. Format is like Lev described, since it is consistent. Note: method destructs input list.

```
A = [[1,'a'],[1,'b'],[2,'c'],[2,'d'],[4,'x'],[5,'y'],[1,'e'],[2,'f']]

def proc_indent(level, input_list):
  if not input_list or level > input_list[0][0]:
    return None
  this_level = input_list.pop(0)[1] if level == input_list[0][0] else None
  up_levels = []
  while True:
    r = proc_indent(level+1, input_list)
    if r is None:
      break
    up_levels.append( r )
  if not up_levels:
    return [this_level]
  up_levels = [i for u in up_levels for i in u]
  return [this_level, up_levels] if this_level else [up_levels]

print proc_indent(0, list(A))  # copy list, since it is destructed in a recursion
```