# Creating list structure based on depth values for the items in Python

Tags: python, list

Im trying to create a list structure in a list of strings given the depth of each string.
I have no clue on how to code this. A step in the right direction would be appreciated.

```
strings = ["tree", "branch", "leaf", "leaf", "leaf", "branch", "tree", "tree", "branch", "tree"]
depths  = [1,2,3,3,3,2,1,1,2,1]
```

What im trying to get:

```
strings = ["tree", ["branch", ["leaf", "leaf", "leaf"], "branch"], "tree","tree", ["branch"], "tree"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution for your question.
First get maximum value in the depths and decrement level by 1. If consecutive level, then append to previous array. I hope you will get it.

> Whenever you try to solve these question, make a plan for how will you
>   get to the solution and use debugger to see if your code is performing
>   as you expected or not.

```
import copy

strings = ["tree", "branch", "leaf", "leaf", "leaf", "branch", "tree", "tree", "branch", "tree"]
depths  = [1,2,3,3,3,2,1,1,2,1]
output = copy.deepcopy(depths)

while max(depths)!=0:
    m = max(depths)
    last = -2
    while True:
        try:
            i = depths.index(m)
            depths[i]=m-1
            if i-1==last:
                output[i-1].append(strings[i] if isinstance(output[i], int) else output[i])
                last=i-1
                output.pop(i)
                depths.pop(i)
                strings.pop(i)
                continue
            else:
                output[i] = [strings[i]]
                last=i
        except:
            break

print(output[0])
#output[0] = ['tree', ['branch', ['leaf', 'leaf', 'leaf'], 'branch'], 'tree', 'tree', ['branch'], 'tree']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14081005/python-read-a-list-with-tree-depth-level-and-output-a-tree-like-nested-list). They may have some common factors. Anyway, I recommend you to search online for BFS and DFS algorithms because they are useful for your case.